# Grep: how to use?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with three columns and two rows.

```
1 2 3
4 5 9
```

I want to use the "grep" command to find the column number of the 9. I already know it will be second row. So:

```
grep(9, ds[2,])
```

It doesn't work (i.e. returns `integer(0)`).

However, the other way around, if I want to know in which row number the 9 is and I know the column number it does work

```
grep(9, de[,3])
```

That will return the answer 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep()` is not appropriate here, you can use numeric matching instead.  If you know the rows and columns as you state, then you can match with `which()` after an equality match `==`.

```
> ds <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9), nrow = 2)
> ds
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    9
> which(ds[2,]==9)
[1] 3
> which(ds[,3]==9)
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Do not use regex functions if you are not dealing with character strings. Use `which`:

```
m <- rbind(1:3, c(4, 5, 9))
which(m == 9, arr.ind = TRUE)
#     row col
#[1,]   2   3
```